# can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float' while I try to resize img from PIL

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

```
def main_convertation(img, Width, Height):
    width, height = Width, Height
    text_file = open('result.txt', 'w')
    scaleFactor = 0.1
    oneCharWidth = 8
    oneCharHeight = 12
    img.resize((int(scaleFactor * width), int(scaleFactor * height * (oneCharWidth / oneCharHeight))),
           PilImage.NEAREST)
    pixels = img.load()
    outputImage = PilImage.new('RGB', (oneCharWidth * width, oneCharHeight * height), color=(30, 30, 30))
    d = PilImageDraw.Draw(outputImage)
```

I have error: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float', but dont know why. I take width and height from user input in terminal window using (n)curses. Help pls! :D

Comment: Can you post the full error?

Comment: Please add to the question what the parameters `Width` and `Height` are.  I suspect one of these is a list or tuple - that situation would certainly give this error.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 119, in <module>
    curses.wrapper(main)
  File "C:\Users\Никита\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\curses\__init__.py", line 105, in wrapper
    return func(stdscr, *args, **kwds)
  File "main.py", line 104, in main
    main_convertation(img, width_of_result, height_of_result)
  File "main.py", line 65, in main_convertation
    img.resize((int(scaleFactor * width), int(scaleFactor * height * int(oneCharWidth / oneCharHeight))),
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'

Comment: If you want to see full project go to my GItHub. I'm a begginer programmer and my code is very terreble, but i try to improve it

Comment: i take width and height from terminal using n(curses librery to take user input from it)